# Why Animal is a superclass to Lion but Vehicle is a interface that Car implements?

Tags: java, interface

We have 2 Kinds of Relationship:

1. `Animal- Lion (Superclass-Subclass)`
2. `Vehicle - Car (Interface- Class that implements it)`

Why `Animal` is a superclass to `Lion` but `Vehicle` is a interface that `Car` implements?

Comment: Depends on the code… Can you show it?

Comment: choice made by the person who designed the code